# apache rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm trying to get the following url to be rewritten

```
http://blog.mywebsite.com:8080/wp-admin/users.php?paged=2
```

as

```
http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-admin/users.php?paged=2
```

i have tried a variety of rewrite conditions and rules

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule blog.mywebiste.com(.*)$ mywebsite.com/blog/$1
```

i seem to loose the query string when id do this

```
RewriteRule ^/wp-admin(.*) http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-admin$1
```

this doesn't seem to catch it at all

also i have the rewrite log on. When does this get written to?

Answer (score 0):

It should work without leading forward-slash:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)  http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-admin/$1
```